# How to use FeatureLayer's opacity settings?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, symbology, transparency-opacity

I'm pretty new to GIS development and I'm trying to load a FeatureLayer that has opacity set (layer is outlined areas that are color-filled and translucent). However, when the layer is displayed in my app it seems as though it's using default 100% opacity. I can override it within the code and change the opacity myself, but that affects the outline borders and labels that are on the layer.

Looking at the drawing info for the layers on the mapserver, I see the borders have "Transparency: 0", and the areas have "Transparency: 50", which is what I expect.

Is there a specific setting when making the request to honor the opacity settings defined on the server?

ArcGIS JavaScript API v3.23

EDITED: Added the drawing info from the server.

Comment: have you tried setting the "styling" property on the feature layer to "false"